# Problem with using keyboard module and turtle together

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, turtle-graphics

I am writing a script to read my keystrokes and draw simple shapes in turtle.
To record keystrokes, I am using the `keyboard` module and I am using `turtle` for drawing.

I am getting struck due to the use of threading in the `keyboard` module.

What I am currently doing is-

1. I added hotkeys using `keyboard.add_hotkey` method.
2. If I am pressing a certain key, that letter is added to a list (named `data`) for later use.
3. When I press the combination of Ctrl+Shift+S, the save function is called. In the save function, a turtle window is instantiated, and the list `data` is popped one letter at a time. The shape is drawn according to the letter popped.
4. When the list gets empty, I save the drawing and close the turtle window.

The problem that I am facing is that once the save function is called, the program stops listening to other calls. It is perhaps due to the use of threads in `keyboard` module.

The code is attached here-

```
def start():
    #turtle.mainloop()
    s=turtle.Screen().setup( width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, startx = 0, starty = 0)
    global t
    t=turtle.Turtle()
    turtle.ht()
    t.ht()

def save():

    start()
    global t
    global data
    t.speed(0)

    while data:
        fun = data.pop()

        if fun=='c':
            draw_circle()
        elif fun=='r':
            draw_rectangle()
        elif fun=='p':
            draw_polygon()
        elif fun=='h':
            draw_hexagon()
        elif fun=='t':
            draw_triangle()
        elif fun=='m':
            draw_pentagon()

    ts = turtle.getscreen()
    ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="drawing.eps")
    img = Image.open('drawing.eps')
    img.save('drawing.png')
    turtle.bye()

def push_fun(fun):
    data.append(fun)

if __name__=='__main__':
    keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+s', save)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+e', exit)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+p', send_to_server)
    # keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+s', save, args=(data))
    keyboard.add_hotkey('c', push_fun, args=('c',))
    keyboard.add_hotkey('s', push_fun, args=('t',))
    keyboard.add_hotkey('h', push_fun, args=('h',))
    keyboard.add_hotkey('p', push_fun, args=('p',))
    keyboard.add_hotkey('r', push_fun, args=('r',))
    keyboard.wait()
```

After the save function is called, the program remains in the keyboard.wait() part but does not listen to any other key press.

Answer (score 0):

you can end the wait by setting a key to press like:

```
keyboard.wait('space')
```

but keyboard.wait() without any keys given blocks all keystrokes forever

I'm not sure why you even put it there, I'm not even sure why it picks anything up at all, but I think you can do this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    '''your keystrokes'''
    while True: #or set a timer or something
        pass
```

you didn't give me the whole code so I can't make sure it works

you also need to global the list data in the push_fun function

I hope it helps :)

Comment: the `pass` in the `while` loop will cause it to run only once, isn't it?

Comment: @PrashantSengar pass is just a placeholder when there is no code in a loop or a def etc, you are thinking about break :)

Comment: the code still has the same problems. Here is the [full code](https://pastebin.com/FQKNbUGq) if you could help me out